# SwiftUI List View opens same PDF whatever row is selected - also cannot remove extension for list

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am listing an array of PDFs stored in a bundle. However, no matter what row I select it always displays the first item in list. I can't see why this is happening as I am using `pdf[item]` when the sheet is presented.

The other problem I have is that I cannot seem to remove the extension of the documents listed. I have tried adding `dropLast(4)` to `let = pdf` but it doesn't seem to do anything.

**NOTE: (`bundleLoc` changes depending on other selections but for the purpose of explaining I have changed it to `"/Products/PDF"`**

This is where I am listing all the PDFs:

```
struct ProductTab5View: View {
    
    @State var showingDetail = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical){
            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                let bundleLoc = "/Products/PDF"
                let pdf = Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: "pdf", subdirectory: bundleLoc)?
                    .compactMap { $0.lastPathComponent } ?? []
                    .dropLast(4)

                ForEach(0..<pdf.count, id: \.self) { item in
                    Button(action: {
                        self.showingDetail.toggle()
                    }, label: {
                        Text(pdf[item])
                    })
                    .sheet(isPresented: $showingDetail) {
                        PDFKitView(pdfName: pdf[item], pdfLocation: bundleLoc)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a segment of the PDFViewer struct:

```
struct PDFKitView: View {
    
    var pdfName: String
    var pdfLocation: String
    
    var body: some View {
        PDFViewer(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: self.pdfName, withExtension: nil, subdirectory: pdfLocation)!)
            .ignoresSafeArea(edges:.bottom)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues here.

First, to remove the `.pdf` extension you need to use `dropLast(4)` on the *`String`*, not the *`Array`* that is produced by `compactMap`.

Second, You are actually creating a `.sheet` for each iteration of the `ForEach` loop. All of the sheets have their visibility controlled by `$showingDetail`, but you only see the topmost (first) sheet.

I would suggest a few improvements:

1. Store an array of `URL` rather than `String` - That way you don't need to re-create the `URL` in the `PDFKitView`.
2. Use an `@State` var to indicate which `URL` should be shown
3. Iterate over the array directly.  There is no need to use `index`

```
struct ProductTab5View: View {
    
    @State var showingDetail = false
    @State var pdfURL: URL?
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical){
            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                let bundleLoc = "/Products/PDF"
                let pdfs = Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: "pdf", subdirectory: bundleLoc) ?? []
                ForEach(pdfs, id: \.self) { pdf in
                    Button(action: {
                        self.pdfURL = pdf
                        self.showingDetail.toggle()
                    }, label: {
                        Text((pdf.lastPathComponent ?? "").dropLast(4))
                    })
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $showingDetail) {
                        PDFKitView(pdf: self.$pdfURL)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
    
struct PDFKitView: View {
    @Binding var pdf: URL?
    var body: some View {
        if let url = self.pdf { 
            PDFViewer(url: url)
                .ignoresSafeArea(edges:.bottom)
        } else {
            Text("PDF Not found")
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for an in-depth answer! Just to test this I need to add a `@Binding URL` to the previews within the `struct PDFKitView: View`. What would I need to put in there as a `@Binding URL` example?

Comment: You can use any URL that points to a PDF `.constant(URL(string:"https://somewebsite.com/somefile.pdf")!)`

Comment: Without having to write another question or edit this one, is it possible to sort the bundle `let=pdf`? I have tried adding `sorted()` to it but I get the error of `Referencing instance method 'sorted()' on 'Sequence' requires that 'URL' conform to 'Comparable`

Comment: You can't just use `sorted`, you would have to use `sorted` with a trailing closure that performs whatever comparison you want; perhaps sorting by the file name https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/arrays/how-to-sort-an-array-using-sort